# Windows authentication for .net site hosted outside the domain

Tags: asp.net, windows, authentication

Will I able to access ASP.net website hosted on IIS server outside the domain but in the network with integrated windows authentication (AD) enabled? If so what are the configuration changes required?

Comment: I guess not possible.But if you want you need to Make a Trust Relationship with your AD server and with the hosted website AD Server